# A kernel 'more analytic' than $\exp(-x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-functions, kernels

I am looking for an analytic function $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ with $\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) \, dx = 1$ and the property, that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} |c_k| \varepsilon^k (2k)! < \infty$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, if $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k$ is the series representation of $F(x)$ around zero.

$F$ being symmetric around zero would be a nice bonus.

Any help is much appreciated!

---

Second Edit: As Iosif Pinelis correctly pointed out, the below arguments only work for positive definite kernels $F$ so there may still be hope.

---

Edit: Sorry, this might be impossible. By Bochner's Theorem the first two properties $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) \, dx = 1$ hold if and only if the (generalized) Fourier transform $\hat{\mu}$ of $F$ is a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}$. We can then write
\begin{align*}
& F(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i2\pi \xi x} \, d\hat{\mu}(\xi) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^k \underbrace{\frac{(i2\pi)^k}{k!} \overbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} \xi^k \, d\hat{\mu}(\xi)}^{\mathbb{E}[X^k]}}_{c_k} \ .
\end{align*}
Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution $\hat{\mu}$, then the last property is
\begin{align*}
\infty & \overset{!}{>} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{|2\pi|^k}{k!} \big|\mathbb{E}[X^k] \big| \varepsilon^k (2k)!\\
& \geq \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{|2\pi|^{2m}}{(2m)!} \mathbb{E}[X^{2m}] \varepsilon^{2m} (4m)!
\end{align*}
Hoever Jensens inequality gives $\mathbb{E}[X^{2m}] \geq \mathbb{E}[X^2]^{m}$. Since $\mathbb{E}[X^2]>0$, the above sum always diverges.

Comment: I was tinkering on Desmos with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(an)!}$ where $a$ ranged from 1 to 4. It seems that as $a$ increases the total integral underneath the curve increases $a=2$ recovers the cosine and then from there things start to diverge. I might wonder if we restrict our class of functions to $$ \sum_{n=0} c_n(-1)^nx^{2n}$$ where $c_n$ is a monotonically decreasing positive valued function then perhaps this is impossible to do. And for you to find a solution requires a bit more weirdness

Comment: What is an example of something easier ... entire function $F(x) = \sum c_k x^k$, $F(x)>0$ in $(0,\infty)$, $\int_0^\infty F(x)\,dx < \infty$, and $\sum |c_k|<\infty$

Comment: @GeraldEdgar  An example for the more simple case would have been $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, \exp(-x^2)$ with $c_{2k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$

Comment: "By Bochner's Theorem the first two properties $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) \, dx = 1$ hold if and only if the (generalized) Fourier transform $\hat{\mu}$ of $F$ is a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}$." For that, you would need $F$ to be positive definite. Where would you get that from?

Comment: The condition $\sum_{k=0}^\infty |c_k| \varepsilon^k (2k)! < \infty$ does not seem to match the stated goal of "more analytic than $\exp(-x^2)$"; $\sum_{k=0}^\infty |c_k| \varepsilon^k \lfloor k/2 \rfloor! < \infty$ would be more appropriate in that case.

Comment: @TerryTao That is correct and I think such a goal as you stated here is achievable by prescribing the Fourier transform $\hat{F}(\xi) = C e^{-x^4}$. Similarly we could prescribe $\hat{F}(\xi) = C e^{-x^{2N}}$ for fixed large $N$ and might come arbitrarily close to the rate $k!$. I am interested in whether or not one can achieve something beyond the rate $k!$.

Comment: Where do you want the function to be analytic?  Because your domain (0, ∞) does not include 0.

Comment: You can obviously ensure symmetry around zero

Comment: Let $G$ be a nonnegative even function supported on $[-1,1]$ with positive Fourier transform, such as $G(x) = (1-|x|)_+$. Then $F(x) = \hat G(x) = \int \cos(2 \pi xy) G(y) \, dy$ is analytic, nonnegative, has total mass $G(0)$, and the coefficient of $x^k$ is comparable to $1/k!$ ($k$ even) up to an exponential. That is better than $\exp(-x^2)$, but not as good as what the body of the question asks for.

Comment: Cool, thank you! It's further than I've managed.

Comment: I think I have an idea how to use theory of entire functions to show that example of @SeanEberhard is essentially optimal. There's a theorem saying that a function of order less than $\frac{1}{2}$ can not be bounded on a ray, which is very close to being in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ from the point of view of complex analysis, so applying it to $F(\sqrt{z})$ should give us a contradiction by considering a ray $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I mean, Taylor series obviously converges on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ under the assumption from the OP, so it doesn't matter (and throw in some uniqueness theorem to prove that it coincides with the original one on $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$

I will show that if $\sum |c_n| C^n n! < \infty$ for all $C > 0$ then there's no such function $F$ (if we only know it for some fixed $C$ then there are such functions). Note that this condition is equivalent to having a minimal exponential type. The proof is based on the following version of the Phragmén–Lindelöf principle:

$\textbf{Lemma}$ Assume that the function $F$ is analytic in the closed upper half-plane $\{z: Im(z) \ge 0\}$, is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and is of minimal exponential type, that is for all $\eps> 0$ we have $|F(z)| \le C_\eps e^{\eps |z|}$. Then $F$ is bounded on $\{z: Im(z) \ge 1\}$.

Classical Phragmén–Lindelöf principle assumes that $F\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and gives us that $F$ is bounded in $\{z: Im(z) \ge 0\}$.

To get from this lemma and the classical principle our result is easy: by the lemma $F$ is bounded on $\{ z: Im(z) = 1\}$, applying the classical Phragmén–Lindelöf principle to the half-planes $\{z: Im(z) \ge 1\}$ and $\{z: Im(z) \le 1\}$ we get that $F$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$, but then by the Lioville's theorem it is constant, but the constants are not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

So, it remains to prove the lemma, whose proof will mimic that of the Phragmén–Lindelöf principle. We will actually just prove that $F$ is bounded on $\{z: Im(z) = 1\}$ and then invoke the classical Phragmén–Lindelöf principle to finish it off. Consider $G(z) = F(z)e^{iz}$. It is bounded (and in $L^1$) on $\{iy: y \ge 0\}$ and is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. We will deal with $\{z: Re(z) < 0\}$ and $\{z: Re(z) > 0\}$ separately. I will only cover the first case, the other is entirely similar. Note also that the extra factor $e^{iz}$ does not affect boundedness on $\{z: Im(z) = 1\}$.

So, we have a function $G$ which is defined in the sector of angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and of minimal exponential type ($|e^{iz}|\le 1$ in all of our domain) and which is $L^1$ on its boundary and we want to get an upper bound for the values at least $1$ away from said boundary.

By rotation we assume that the angle is $|\arg(z)| \le \frac{\pi}{4}$ and consider $G_\eps(z) = G(z)e^{-\eps z}$. This function tends uniformly to $0$ when $|z|\to \infty$ since $G$ is of minimal type (note that $|e^{-\eps z}| \le e^{-\eps |z|/2}$). We fix $z_0$ which is at least $1$ away from the rays $\arg(z) = \pm \frac{\pi}{4}$. Consider the domain $\Omega$ bounded by these rays and the arc of a circle of radius $R$.

We want to use subharmonicity of $\log |G_\eps(z)|$. Here, unfortunately, we would need one little extra knowledge beyond the usual proof of the Phragmén–Lindelöf principle -- what is the harmonic measure. We want to bound the value of $\log |G_\eps(z_0)|$ via the values on the boundary of our domain, which is achieved by integrating these values at the boundary against the harmonic of $z_0$ with respect to $\Omega$, so we have to somehow bound it.

Harmonic measure on the arc doesn't matter for us since $G_\eps$ on it is at most $1$ anyway if $R$ is big enough in terms of $\eps$. As for the rays, here is a nice cheat: if we enlarge the domain then harmonic measure can only increase. So, for a ray $\arg z = \frac{\pi}{4}$, we can consider the whole half-plane $-\frac{3\pi}{4} \le \arg z \le \frac{\pi}{4}$, on which the harmonic measure is just a Poisson measure, which is uniformly bounded by the Lebesgue measure for all $z_0$ which are at least $1$ away from said ray. And the same for the other ray.

It remains to note that $||\log_{+} |G_\eps| ||_{L^1} \le ||\log_{+}|G|||_{L^1} \le ||G||_{L^1} < \infty$, so we get a uniform upper bound for $G_\eps(z_0)$ by sending $R$ to infinity and this bound does not depend on $\eps$. Now, sending $\eps\to 0$ we get a uniform upper bound on $G(z_0)$ which is exactly what we wanted.

If for some reason you checked the above argument very closely, we actually didn't cover the segment $[-1 + i, 1 + i]$, but it is a compact segment and $F$ is obviously bounded on it.

It turned out to be a bit more verbose than I expected, but what we really did is we just repeated a textbook proof of the Phragmén–Lindelöf principle with a little change using the harmonic measure to cover $L^1$ instead of the $L^\infty$ assumption.

Answer (score 12):

There is no such function. As already suggested by Aleksei in a comment, this follows by putting together some facts about entire functions. I'm almost certainly using machinery that is too heavy here.

First of all, the condition on the Taylor coefficients implies that $F$ is entire of order $\le 1/2$: if, say, $\sum |c_n| (2n)! < \infty$, then we can estimate $|F(z)|\le \sum |c_n| |z|^n$ by cutting off the sum at $N\simeq |z|^{1/2}$.

In particular, $\log_+ |F(x)| \lesssim 1+|x|^{1/2+\epsilon}$ for real $x$, so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log_+ |F(x)|}{1+x^2}\, dx<\infty$, and thus the [Riesz-Fejer theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r-Riesz_theorem) shows that $F=GG^{\#}$, for some entire $G$ of exponential type (and $G^{\#}(z)=\overline{G(\overline{z})}$). [Note that I'm ignoring most of the statement of the theorem, I just use it as a crutch to take a square root of $F$ of sorts.]

Since also $G\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, the Paley-Wiener theorem shows that the Fourier transform $\widehat{G}\in L^2(-R,R)$ is compactly supported, and $G$ has non-zero type ($=R$, if $R$ was minimal). Then the same is true of $F$ since its Fourier transform is also compactly supported, so $F$ has order $1$, but we already saw above that our basic assumption gives $F$ order $\le 1/2$.

Finally, and again as already pointed out by Aleksei, literally the same argument shows that $\sum |c_n|\epsilon^n (An)!<\infty$ is not possible for any $A>1$ (and here we can interpret $(An)!$ as a quantity with the asymptotics suggested by the Stirling formula).

Comment: I was just planning to post an answer, but it seems I was a bit too late :) I had an argument with (a version of) the Phragmén–Lindelöf principle, in particular it should give that there is no such function even of order $1$ and minimal type (your argument shows that there's no such function with order strictly less than $1$, I don't know if you can push it to minimal type).

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov: I think it would be good to have your answer also, especially since mine feels rather make-shift and was based on your ideas anyway.

Comment: Actually, your answer gives the same as mine: we can bound $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log_{+}|F(x)|}{1+x^2}dx$ simply via $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |F(x)|dx$, so we can apply Riesz--Fejer regardless of the growth. Where you need the growth is in the end where you use Paley--Wiener.

Answer (score 7):

If "more analytic" means "faster decrease of Tylor coefficients", you can have a kernel "more analytic then normal". Your condition implies that $F$ is entire, of order $1/2$. Such functions cannot be integrable on the real line.

On the other hand, $\exp(-x^2)$ has order $2$, for it $|c_n|=1/(n/2)!$. The smallest order of entire function which allows bounded (or integrable) functions on the real line
is $1$. So you can have a kernel with coefficients like $1/n!$, for example,
$$\frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{x^2}.$$
The formula for the order of an entire function
$$\rho=\limsup\frac{n\log n}{\log(1/|c_n|)}$$
can be found, for example in Levin's book Distribution of zeros of entire functions, Chap. I, sect. 2, Theorem 2.