# A probability distribution, with Fourier transform smaller than $C \exp(-ct^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, fourier-transform

Is there a probability distribution $\mu$ (with reasonably nice density $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$) such that the Fourier transform (aka. characteristic function) $\psi_\mu(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx} \, d\mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx} f(x) \, dx$ converges to zero for $t \rightarrow \pm\infty$ faster than $\exp(-ct^2)$ for arbitrarily large $c>0$?

The rate $\exp(-ct^2)$ is achieved by the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ for $\sigma^2 \geq 2c$, since $\psi_{\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)}(t) = e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}}$.

Any help is much apprechiated!

---

This question is somewhat related to a previous question ([A kernel 'more analytic' than $\exp(-x^2)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451657/a-kernel-more-analytic-than-exp-x2)). Due to the negative result given to that question, I am now shifting my focus to kernels on $\mathbb{S}_1 \subset \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. E.g., if $f(x)=\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\pi x^2}$ for real $x\ne0$, then $\psi_\mu(t)=\max(0,1-|t|)$ for real $t$ (which latter $=0$ if $|t|\ge1$).

Comment: Thank you for accepting this answer. You may also want to [vote on it](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers).